# How to find based on a null-able property which a specific list contains that in MongoDB and C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a `Cage` object which contains a null-able property `Guid? PetId`now I want to update all cages where `PetId` is in a `List<Guid>` `petIds`

I tried to cast `petIds` to `List<Guid?>` or tried `x => x.PetId != null ? PetId : Guid.Empty` in `In` query expression but doesn't work.

This is my method:

```
public async Task<bool> MyMethodAsync(IEnumerable<Guid> petIds)
{
   var query = Builders<Cage>.Filter.In(x => x.PetId.Value, petIds);
   var updateQuery = Builders<Cage>.Update.Set(x => x.PetId, null);
   var result = await Collection.UpdateManyAsync(query, updateQuery);
   return result.IsAcknowledged;
}
```

All I got is this error `Unable to determine the serialization information for x => x.PetId.Value`

Comment: I could solve this problem by changing `petIds` to `IEnumerable<Guid?>` and that `query` part to `Builders<Cage>.Filter.In(x => x.PetId, petIds)` but is there any better way to do that?

Comment: You could cast it in the filter statement like `Builders<Cage>.Filter.In(x => x.PetId.Value, petIds.Select(p => (Guid?)p);`

Comment: Thank you @Skami, but MongoDB can not serialize `x.PetId.Value`, so you would get same error.

Comment: You are correct but wouldn't  `Builders<Cage>.Filter.In(x => x.PetId, petIds.Select(x => (Guid?)x));` suffice?

Comment: Thank you, yes it is correct but it is basically same code. Casting `PetId` to `Guid?`.

Comment: Not entirely cause the the `petIds.Select(..` part casts the Guids to nullables in the application, while the other tries to do so on in a query on Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

how about simply using `Guid.Empty` instead of null? i.e. you have to store PetID as Guid and have a default value of Guid.Empty in the class declaration.

here's a demonstration:

```cs
using System;
using MongoDB.Entities;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Cage : Entity
        {
            public Guid PetID { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            var cage1 = new Cage { PetID = Guid.NewGuid() };
            cage1.Save();

            var cage2 = new Cage {};
            cage2.Save();

            var list = new[] { cage1.PetID, Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() };

            DB.Update<Cage>()
              .Match(f => f.In(c => c.PetID, list))
              .Modify(c => c.PetID, Guid.Empty)
              .Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

above code is using [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) which is a convenience library for the c# driver. [disclaimer: i'm the author of the library]

Comment: Thank you, That was my first approach but then I needed to change it to null-able.